# How to configure iptables to route specific services tos pecific worstations?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, iptables

May not be the best question title. I'll try to explain better.
Also, I'm no firewalling expert.

I have a linux box/router based on debian (it's a dreamplug in case it makes a difference). The firewalling part is something I implemented over 10 years ago in RH4 I believe, and subsequently ported it over the years to CentOS 5, 6 and a couple years ago to this dreamplug (I'll call it DP to be short).

Long story short: the iptables rules allow specific services to run on the DP, some are open to public, some are private. Also, the rules forward some of the public services to a couple LAN servers. More to it, DP controls the internet access and ever since I implemented this, I have only 2 optins: either a workstation receives internet access (to everything) or it does not, at all. It does this for the LAN and for the WAN. I do that by having a SNAT for each and FORWARD rules for the workstations that are allowed internet access from the LAN.

Now I'm in the situation where I have a workstation that is by policy in the no internet zone, but as with everything when it comes to policies, it now "needs" access to dropbox (cause that's how they resolved some other issues outside my network, so lansync is not an option, unless I fire up another VM just for that, but it's overkill).

So I need to somehow allow specific ip+port combinations to go in/out for specific workstations, instead of a couple FORWARD rules for the LAN IP.

I'm guessing I need to SNAT for each of the ip+port but I'm not successful for some reason.
I tried the most basic SNAT as

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s WS_ip -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source DP_IP
```

but no luck.

eth0 is internet. eth1 is the LAN, WS_IP is in LAN, DP_IP is on eth0

I'm open to other solutions as long as I don't have to rewrite my firewall, since I have quite a few scripts, local and remote, that deal with this firewall and the way it is implemented.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a lot more simple than I thought.

I don't recall seeing this in any of the tutorials I've read, which is why I didn't think of the possibility till now.

Actually, the FORWARD chain allows the same filtering as any of the other chains (input/output) with whatever possible specifics.

To keep things short, after trying all sort of SNATs to no success, I figured, let's try a FORWARD rule in the same manner as the other chains, eg:

```
*filter
:partinet - [0:0]
:dropbox - [0:0]
-A partinet -p icmp -j ACCEPT

-A dropbox -p tcp -d 162.125.32.129 -j ACCEPT
-A dropbox -p tcp -s 162.125.32.129 -j ACCEPT
-A dropbox -p tcp -d 162.125.17.131 -j ACCEPT
-A dropbox -p tcp -s 162.125.17.131 -j ACCEPT

-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.x -j partinet
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.x -j partinet
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.x -j dropbox
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.x -j dropbox

COMMIT
```

You want to have ICMP allowed because windows and maybe other apps use it  (and maybe HTTP) to check for internet connection. For Win7 at least, ICMP is sufficient.

So this is a minimum iptables script for the job. You can further filter by destination port (443). You will obviously need to maintain the list of IP's.
Not exactly a fun thing to do manually. I'll think about automating that when it's going to be annoying.